# facebook /v2.1/oauth/authorize do not redirect to /v2.1/dialog/oauth

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I try move canvas-app to v2.1 api.
So when an user are authorizing to the app
I send

> [protocol://]graph.facebook.com/v2.1/oauth/authorize?client_id=XXXX&scope=&redirect_uri=XXXXX

and got redirect to

> [protoco://]www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=XXXX&scope=&redirect_uri=XXXXX

which is dialog from API version 1

I expect to get dialog API version 2.1

> [protocol://]www.facebook.com/v2.1/dialog/oauth?client_id=XXXX&scope=&redirect_uri=XXXXX

how can I reach it?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm getting the same problem now.

Comment: I've filed a [Facebook bug report](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/872023706175695/)

Comment: Is that /authorize endpoint still supported? I thought /dialog/oauth was the correct path now?

Answer (score 2):

We were stumped on this and then we checked our App Settings, under Migrations, and this problem went away when we turned on "Use Graph API v2.0 by default". Hope that helps.

[image]

Comment: This solution, unfortunately, points the user to 2.0 and not 2.1 like they wanted.

Answer (score 1):

We encountered the same issue.  We fixed it by just linking directly to the new URL:

https://www.facebook.com/v2.1/dialog/oauth?client_id=XXXX&scope=&redirect_uri=XXXXX